# Ember tests: checkbox

Tags: ember.js, ember-testing

I'm developing ember tests and I want to check if error messages are correctly displayed.
For that I need to check a specific checkbox (or groups of checkboxes) from a list.
Is there a way to specify which checkboxes we want?
Maybe using some kind of parameter that we can pass to choose which we want to select?
Thanks

Comment: Use a selector. You'll maybe find [ember-test-selectors](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-test-selectors) useful.

Comment: That is what I am using: `checkbox: clickable( '.checkbox:eq(0)'),`
But my list is dynamic and I didn't want to duplicate code and just change the index...

Comment: Why don't you show your current code so we can understand what problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I figure out how to solve it. I used a collection to identify the elements.
Thanks all for your help!

```
//products.js

export default create({
  main: {
    scope: '#main',
    allProducts: collection({
      itemScope: '.products-list',
      item: {
        name: text('.card-h1'),
        click: clickable('.card-h1'),
        color: text('.product-color'),
        quantity: text('.product-quantity'),
      },
    }),
  }
});

// products-test.js

function getSingleProduct(name) {
  return products.main.allProducts()
    .filter(p => p.name.trim() === name).get(0);
}

assert.equal(product.color, 'red');
assert.equal(product.quantity, 10);
```

Comment: That's great news. To help our everyone else please add your solution so future searchers will be able to see what you did to make it work and then mark this answer as correct.

Comment: This doesn't look like the [default way to write tests in Ember](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/testing/). Seems like you are using [Ember CLI Page Object](http://ember-cli-page-object.js.org/docs/v1.17.x/), aren't you? Mainly commenting so that other people don't get confused when seeing that code example.